# Should we regard a capillary tube as a source of potential energy?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, surface-tension, capillary-action

When a capillary tube is inserted into a large body of water, there is an increase in potential energy (PE) of the system. This is because the increase in PE of the rising water in the capillary is greater than the loss of PE of the body of the water. The increase in height of the capillary water is greater than the loss of height of the body of water, and the same mass is involved.

Is an empty capillary tube really a source of potential energy?

Comment: Re, "...potential energy...of the system." You are not considering the _whole_ system. You are correct as far as _gravitational_ potential energy is concerned, but that's not the only form of energy in play. It's more complicated than I know how to describe (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action), but in a nut shell, water entering the capillary tube _lowers_ the overall energy state of the system.

Comment: Indeed, A dry glass surface has higher energy than a wet one.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was looking at it from an applied mechanics point of view. I’ve got a bit of reading to do